# Unable to reproduce the issue reported by apple app store review team

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, ios9.1

I have a live app in app store that was published before iOS 9.0 was released. Then we submitted an update after iOS 9 was released. App got rejected with following reason "**The app hangs on a load screen unless the user closes the app and relaunches**"

> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad
>   running iOS 9.1 and iPhone running iOS 9.1 on both Wi-Fi and cellular
>   networks.
>
> The app hangs on a load screen unless the user closes the app and
>   relaunches
>
> The steps to reproduce are:
>
> 1. Launch app
> 2. A screen with the apps logo will appear indefinitely
> 3. Close app
> 4. Launch app again and a login screen will appear

**I can't reproduce the issue from my side. I tried to reproduce this using following 2 ways.**

***1. From itunes***

- Copied ipa to itunes Apps in my mac.
- Connected iPhone running iOS 9.1 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.
- Installed ipa to above mentioned device.
- After completing the install, Launch app
- A screen with the app logo will appear after that login screen will appear.

***2. Tried as an internal tester from itunesconnect (TestFlight)***

- Connected iPhone running iOS 9.1 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.
- Installed ipa from Testflight app.
- After completing the install, Launch app
- A screen with the app logo will appear after that login screen will appear.

Now we replied to appstore that we can't reproduce the issue. But it seems they will take time to reply for us. So am trying to get suggestions from all.

Comment: Did you try to run the app an an iPad, too? Anyway, it is unlikely to get a definitive answer here unless you provide the source code for the app so that SO users can try to reproduce the error.

Comment: @tilo - Thanks for your quick response. Now i tried it in iPad. it was working good. In which part of source code is need to provide definitive answer. sorry, I can't able to share full source code for security reason.

Comment: I didn't assume that you are going to share the full source code for the app. This is why I hypothesized that you are not going to find the answer to your question on StackOverflow.

Comment: I am also stucking with same problem please help.

Comment: Did you end up finding a way to reproduce the bug?

Answer (score 1):

Did you delete the app from the iOS device (and perhaps reset the device and all Privacy warnings) before installing and testing the app?  Did you try testing the app with the device in Airplane mode (bad or no connectivity during launch)?